# How can I tell if my Minecraft server is accessible online?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I tell if my server is available online to everyone in the world? Port checkers say port 25565 is unblocked in my IP. Does this mean it is OK? I have also successfully port forwarded. Is this OK?

Comment: when you say port checker, do you mean an [online port checker](http://canyouseeme.org/)?

Comment: If you want to answer your own question (perfectly valid), fill out an answer in the space below (where it says "Your Answer") and post.

Comment: Honestly probably the simplest way to check is to ask someone to log in.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the port checkers you mentioned. But you can't really be sure unless you actually have someone connect to the server.

I once had a problem with this; it was on a local network, the computers saw each other, but still it didn't work. We always got an error message and were disconnected. Interestingly enough, when we tried switching the computers, the connection worked normally. (We never resolved this issue.)

In general, there are quite a few things that could go wrong. In case you have problems with connectivity, check the *game configuration*, your *firewall* settings and in case you are behind a router, check *its* configuration. You will have to at least set port forwarding up.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test if your server is publicly accessible by typing your server's public IP address into Minecraft.

You can find out your IP address by browsing to http://www.whatismyip.com or searching for `IP` into Google, and then add your port onto the end like this: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port`

Comment: I do this for my webservers and this always works

Comment: This is a way to figure out your server IP, but not to test whether it is accessible from Internet

Comment: @lispmachine Actually it is. Type the IP into Minecraft.

Comment: @ryansworld10 If connection can be made from within the LAN that does not mean the server is accessible from outside (some firewall may block connection / NAT in use).  In fact in case of NAT you may even not be able to connect to server public IP from LAN, but it doesn't mean it's down.

Comment: Actually, @lispmachine, you are incorrect. Since you are using the "external ip" the connection actually goes OUT and then BACK in. Therefor, if you can connect to it, anyone can. If he had said to use your local ip however, (192.168.1.x) it MAY connect for you and not your friends. (I actually had an issue earlier today in fact, where I couldn't even connect to my server (from the sane machine) because my IP address changed from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.7, but as soon as I forwarded the port on the new IP address, it logged right in.

Comment: @ChaseFleming I beg to disagree.  Firstly port forwarding on your router may or may not forward connections from LAN to external IP and redirect them back to server in LAN.  As a mater of fact I tested it with my router and it does not forward connections in such a way.  Secondly, although this is uncommon, a firewall may be blocking incoming connections from the Internet.